# Remove apostrophe from multiple filenames

Tags: command-line, rename, mv

I'm new with Linux and I have the following problem. I have several different filenames like:

```
'Name1.mp4'
'Name2.mp4'
...
```

I would like to have the apostrophe `'` removed from the filenames. Meaning, in the result I like to have the following:

```
Name1.mp4
Name2.mp4
...
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this? And give me perhaps an explanation whith the `mv` or `rename`  command to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do the quotes actually include the extension? I mean, your files are indeed like `'Name1.mp4'` or are they like `'Name1'.mp4`?

Comment: If you are relying on the output of `ls`, the quotes may not really be there - see for example [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

Comment: If your filenames are as you describe, then solutions are below ... Otherwise, if your filenames are quoted in the output of `ls` because they have spaces, tabs, newline characters ... etc. then see what @steeldriver has linked and you don't need any of the below mentioned solutions in that case.

Comment: Can you try listing these file names with `ls -N` or `ls | cat`?

Comment: Thanks  for your answers. Here the answers to the questions:
- Yes, the apostrophes include the filename and its extension -> 'Name1.mp4'
- If I list up the files in the folder and you're right the apostrophes popped up in a sudden. However I already renamed one file name and this one does not. One more info regarding the filenam. The also contain some spaces between the words -> 'Bla Bla Bla.mp4'. I will check the commend of @steeldriver as you suggested.

Comment: @RalfHütter All given answers should handle spaces in filenames correctly. Can you [edit] your question and post the output of `ls -N` from within the directory containing your files, as FedKad suggested above? The `-N` option will show the literal form of your files, so we can see if they actually contain the quotes or if the quotes are shown by  `ls` for the files that contain spaces.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Thanks a lot for helping me. I checkd my files according to the commends above. It seems that my file names contain spaces and also &/' within the filenames. This is in the end the root cause of the apostophes in my files. I consider this question therefore as closed. Thanks to all for your kind help and support.

Answer (score 6):

This will replace all `'` by nothing for files ending in `.mp4'`.

```
rename "s/'//g if -f" *.mp4\'
```

`rename` might not be installed so run `sudo apt install rename`  to install  it.

Example:

```
$ touch "'1222.mp4'"
$ rename -n "s/'//g if -f" *.mp4\'
rename('1222.mp4', 1222.mp4)
```

`-n` does not change the files, only shows the results. Remove the `-n` to execute the command.

Answer (score 5):

Another nice option is using [`mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/mmv.1.html) (install it using `sudo apt install mmv`). If indeed your filenames are of the form `'Name1.mp4'` you can run:

```
mmv -n "'*.mp4'" "#1.mp4"
```

If you are satisfied with the output, remove `-n` to apply the renaming.

Comment: Notice this (like the `rename` solution) will attempt to rename matching directories as well.

Comment: @Raffa Haha, true, though a bit unlikely (or maybe poor naming) to have a directory ending with `.mp4` inside a directory containing files ending with `.mp4`. ;)

Comment: ... if that's a problem, you could switch to `zsh` and use its contributed `zmv` module, which provides a similar syntax to `mmv` but may be combined with the shell's builtin glob qualifiers to select regular files only, ex. `zmv -Qw -n "'*.mp4'(.)" '$1.mp4'`

Answer (score 4):

In a Bash loop and `mv`, so no installation is required ...

Test a dry-run first with:

```bash
for f in *\'*; do [ -f "$f" ] && ! [ -d "${f//\'/}" ] && echo mv -nv -- "$f" "${f//\'/}"; done
```

... and if that's what you want, then rename with:

```bash
for f in *\'*; do [ -f "$f" ] && ! [ -d "${f//\'/}" ] && mv -nv -- "$f" "${f//\'/}"; done
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the prompt answers and the kind support. I tried all mentioned solutions. However none of them worked out. The ended with an error. This is the outcome:
file or folder could not be found

Comment: @RalfHütter You're welcome ... However, the only cases you can get that output (error) from the solutions in Rinzwind's and BeastOfCaerbannog's answers is if your filenames don't follow the pattern `'somename.mp4'` or if you are running them from within a different directory than the one containing your files (you need to **first** change directory to where your files are located) and I tested both solutions and they should work ... As for the solution in my answer, it should never give you such an error although you also, similarly, need to first change directory for it to work.